# has sqlite been renamed to sqlite3?

Tags: ubuntu, database, ruby, sqlite

I use sqlite for lightweight programming here and there in the Ruby language.  I've noticed something odd.  I use ruby gem `sqlite3` to interact with the sqlite db.

I recently checked out the versions that I have.

`sqlite3 -version` gives me
`3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57 0c55d179733b46d8d0ba4d88e01a25e10677046ee3da1d5b1581e86726f2alt1`

Not necessarily the most recent version but it's listed on the sqlite website.

`gem list sqlite3` gives me 
`sqlite3 (1.4.0, 1.3.13)`

**But** `sqlite -version` gives me 
`2.8.17`

I try to update to `sqlite --version 3.28.0` with 
`sudo apt upgrade sqlite` but this gives me:
`sqlite is already the newest version (2.8.17-14fakesync1).`

I then head over to the ubuntu site and read the summary for this piece of software.  It is designed for sqlite2.  So my question is has `sqlite` changed its name to `sqlite3`.  I do not see any mention of this change? **Perplexed**.

Answer (score 0):

Current Sqlite is version 3.28...

Versions (2.x versus 3.x) can have incompatibilities and so can coexist for a while.

- SQLite V3 appeared in 2004.
- The last release of SQLite V2 (2.8.17) was in December 2005. This seems to be your `sqlite`. I would be wary of any application that still uses it, though :)
- SQLite V1 was too short-lived to stick around.

The [full (his)story](https://sqlite.org/changes.html).

So:

- `sqlite -version` gives you the version/release of an SQLite V2 command line to handle SQLite V2 databases, which is also likely the version of your SQLite library.
- `sqlite3 -version` is the same for an SQLite V3 command/library.
- `gem list sqlite3` gives you the version of the language binding for SQLite V3, which is versioned independently of the releases of the SQLite V3 library, the binging being assumed to work with any SQLite V3 release that you may have installed.

Comment: so my `sqliteV3 is 3.22` then (which is fine it matches what is on sqlite.org) but why is it called sqlite3...the name conflicts with the `sqlite3 gem`.  And I can access `sqliteV2` simply by typing `sqlite` into my terminal and  I can access `sqliteV3` by typing in `sqlite3` into my terminal. It seems someone messed up with the numbering for `SQLiteV2`. No?

Comment: See improved answer